# saga and redux in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, saga

i trying to learn how to work with saga and redux in react, and have same problem. When i trying get data from my backend by using fetch, all works fine

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState({ user: [{
    display: '',
    id: ''
  }] });
```

Fetch:

```
function fetchUsers(query, callback) {
    if (!query) return;
    fetch(`/api/user/finduser/${query}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => res.map(user => ({ display: `@${user.nickname}`, id: user.id })))
      .then(callback);
  }
```

But when i tried to rewrite this code with saga and reducer I have problem, i cant put my data to setUsers

Saga:

```
    function* getAllUsersMentions(action) {
      try {
        const response = yield call(viewPageService.getAllUserMentions, action.payload);
        const usersList = { users: response };
        yield put(getAllUserRoutine.success(response));
        toastr.success('Success', 'get user');
      } catch (error) {
        yield put(getAllUserRoutine.failure(error?.message()));
   }
```

Service:

```
getAllUserMentions: async nickname => api.get(`/api/user/finduser/${nickname}`)
```

Reducer:

```
  [getAllUserRoutine.SUCCESS]: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<IUsers>) => {
    payload.users.map(user => state.users.push(user));
  }
```

IUser:

```
export interface IUsers {
  users: [
   IMentionsUser
  ];
}
```

IMentionsUser:

```
export interface IMentionsUser {
  id: string;
  nickname: string;
}
```

mapStateToProps:

```
users: state.viewPostReducer.data.users
```

mapDispatchToProps:

```
getUsers: getAllUserRoutine
```

IAction:

```
getUsers: IBindingCallback1<object>;
```

user:

```
users: IUsers;
```

Put data from redux and saga to array in another components who displayed data

```
useEffect(() => {
    setUsers(getUsers.map(user => ({ display: `@${user.nickname}`, id: user.id })));
  }, []);
```

I pass array of nicknames and user ids to the component that displays the name and id, but unfortunately my data does not appear.
What am I doing wrong? Can you point out my mistakes and explain how to do it?

Edit: A small addition, I pass this data to the component https://github.com/signavio/react-mentions, which displays users that can be mentioned

```
getAllUsersRequest: reducerCreator([getAllUserRoutine.TRIGGER])
```

---

```
export const getUsersLoading = state => reqs(state).getAllUsersRequest.loading;
export const getUsersError = state => reqs(state).getAllUsersRequest.error;
```

---

```
 export const getAllUserRoutine = createViewPostRoutine('GET_ALL_USERS');
```

store.ts

```
declare global {
  interface Window { // eslint-disable-line
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__?: typeof compose;
  }
}

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-mixed-operators
  && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({ trace: true, traceLimit: 25 } as any) || compose;

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)));

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

root saga:

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    /* PlopJS sagas placeholder. Do not remove */
    viewPostSagas(),
    defaultSagas()
  ]);
}
```

Comment: where are you dispatching the action which triggers your `getAllUsersMentions` ?

Comment: @Shyam I'm not sure if I got it right, but I added a few lines at the end of the question

Comment: You need to tell saga that when an xyz action is dispatched , run this function `getAllUsersMentions` . Are we doing that ? Can you add your file where you are configuring your store ? .

Comment: @Shyam It is quite possible that not, since I do not really understand how to do this.

Comment: @Shyam i add store.ts

Comment: what is rootSaga ? can you add that as well .

Comment: @Shyam add, but in root saga i have only default and my saga, i haven't another saga in my project